# Bad Data Error while decrypting session key

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

With Reference to the MSDN link [Session Key Decrption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.security.cryptography.rsapkcs1keyexchangedeformatter.decryptkeyexchange.aspx) I am trying to decrypt the session key, but I am getting bad data exception at

```
aes.Key = keyDeformatter.DecryptKeyExchange(splitter.EncryptedSecretKey);
```

I verified that I am using correct private key to decrypt, i am getting bad data error. Can any one guide me to get out of this error?

Comment: Did you try to use the [larger example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.security.cryptography.rsapkcs1keyexchangedeformatter.aspx) or did you get to the input in a different way? Could you at least post the stacktrace? Note that just indicating this single line and the "bad data error" is simply not enough for us to find a solution to your question...